# How to solve rod cutting p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m with limit on maximum no. of cuts allowed?

Tags: algorithm

I know how rod cutting problem is solved using dynamic programming.
But when we have limit on maximum no of cuts that is allowed, dynamic programming fails to give correct answer.Even I couldn't think of a recursive solution for the problem. Help.

HERE IS THE PROBLEM,
Determine the maximum revenue obtainable by cutting up the rod and selling the pieces.
Given a rod of length N, and table of prices P(i) for the rod of length i.You can make no more than K cuts on the given rod.

example:
N=10
K=3
| p(1) = 1 | p(2) = 5 | p(3) = 8 | p(4) = 9 |p(5) = 10| p(6) = 22 | p(7) = 17 | p(8) = 20 | p(9) = 24 | p(10) = 30 |

maximum obtainable revenue is 31 by cutting the rod into 2 pieces (total no of cuts =1 which is less than K=3) of length 6 and 4.

Comment: I doubt that DP (as approach) fails to give correct answer. Perhaps you didn't modify it properly to account for cuts' limit.

Comment: Because the problem dont have optimal substructure, DP is not applicable.

Comment: Also please share your solution, if you can come up with one. Thank you

Comment: You even have not shown problem formulation (there are numerous problems with such name)

Comment: I have included the problem itself.

Comment: OK, now problem is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can extend the dynamic programming solution by adding a 2nd dimension which is the number of cuts thus far.

`D[n][k]`, the maximum revenue for a rod of length `n` using exactly `k` cuts, can be defined as follows:

```
D[n][k] = max(price[i] + D[n-i-1][k-1]) for all i in {1, 2, ..., n}
```

Since we want *at most* `K` cuts, not *exactly*, the maximum revenue will be:

```
maxRevenue(N) = max(D[N][k]) for all k in {1, 2, ..., k}
```

This will be `O(N²K)`, since we need to loop over all `k` (compared to `O(N²)` for the classic problem).

---

(Java) code for this:

```java
int[] price = {1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 22, 17, 20, 24, 30};
int N = price.length;
int K = 3;
int[][] D = new int[N+1][K+1];

for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++)
    D[n][0] = price[n-1];

for (int k = 1; k <= K; k++)
for (int n = 0; n <= N; n++)
for (int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
    D[n][k] = Math.max(D[n][k], price[i] + D[n-i-1][k-1]);

int best = 0;
for (int k = 0; k <= K; k++)
    best = Math.max(best, D[N][k]);

System.out.println(best);
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/7WTEDI).