# Dynamic Programming - Rod Cutting Problem with maximum cuts and actual solution

Tags: java, python, dynamic-programming

So I'm trying to write code for a modified version of the [rod cutting problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cutting-a-rod-dp-13/). The link gives a good intuition of the problem. However, I want to modify the code to not only actually return the solution, i.e. what cuts give the optimal solution, but also limit the number of cuts to a maximum of k.

For proof of concept, I'm trying to create an algorithm to achieve this. The following is what I have so far, I think it successfully returns the actual solution, however, I can't figure out how to limit the maximum to k.

```
 let r[0..n] be a new array
 r[0] = 0
 for j = 1 to n
    q = -1
    for i = 1 to j
        for k = 0 to n-1
          q = Math.max(q[n][k], p[i] + q[n-i-1][k-1]);
    r[j] = q
 return r[n]
```

Please do not provide with actual code in your answers, I want to implement that myself, I just need help tweaking my algorithm to give the correct solution.

Update 1: I am already able to find optimal solution for a maximum of k cuts by adding a second dimension to my array. This is shown in the above code.

Comment: What programming language do you use? Please add suitable tag to your question to attract possible answerers.

Comment: have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149463/how-to-solve-rod-cutting-problem-with-limit-on-maximum-no-of-cuts-allowed

Comment: @Sanyash i was looking for a general algorithm, which is why didn't add language tags.

Comment: @Maximus I have. That question only solves the problem of maximum cuts, which I already have implemented. I'm looking for a way to also remember the cuts that are being made.

Comment: @ChingLing That isn't clear from your question. Can you edit and update? What do you mean by "way to remember"

Comment: @Maximus Sorry, I updated the question. What I mean by a way to remember is for the exact lengths of cuts to be stored in an array perhaps, which can then be returned with the maximum profit i.e. how much profit can be achieved by making which cuts?

Comment: @ChingLing In that link: "D[n][k], the maximum revenue for a rod of length n using exactly k cuts". Isn't this what you mean by remembering? That function gives you the maximum revenue per cut. Do you want not the maximum revenue and just any revenue generated by any arbitrary cut to be stored in a hashmap?

Comment: @Maximus I want the maximum revenue and the cuts you made to get that maximum revenue, the cuts to get that max profit are what I'm looking for right now, since the max revenue for k cuts is already done

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you already have the optimal solution, this answer includes only how to retrace the exact solution (cuts made at each step).

### Store the candidate cut for length = n and maximum cuts = k

For this, you simply need a 2-d array (say, `visit[n][k]`) to store the cut made that gets the maximum solution to `q[n][k]`. In terms of pseudo code and recurrence relations, it will look like the following.

```
for each value of i:
  q[n][k] = q[n][k-1]
  visit[n][k] = -1
  if q[n][k] < p[i] + q[n-i-1][k-1]:
    q[n][k] = p[i] + q[n-i-1][k-1]
    visit[n][k] = i
```

#### Explanation

- It is possible that we don't have a cut that maximizes the solution. In this case, we initialize `visit[n][k] = -1`.
- Every time, we have a candidate to cut the rod of length `n` at `length=i+1`, ie. we could get a better price by a cut, we will store the respective cut in another 2-d array.

### Reconstruct the solution

Using this 2-d array (`visit[n][k]`), to back trace the exact cuts, you can use the following pseudo code (I am deliberately avoiding code since you mentioned you don't need it).

```
cuts = []
while k > 0:
  i = visit[n][k]
  if i != -1
    // If there is a cut
    cuts.push(i + 1)
    n = n - i - 1
  k = k - 1
```

#### Explanation

- We iterate from `k` to `0`.
- Every time, when `visit[n][k]` is not `-1`, ie. it is optimal to cut somewhere, we reassign `n` after making the cut, ie. n = n - i - 1 and store the resultant `cut` in the array `cuts`.
- Finally, `cuts` will contain the exact cuts that led to the optimal solution.

Please note that the pseudo code present in your question is slightly incorrect in terms of variables used in the recurrence relation. `q` is used both to store the DP 2-d array as well as an integer `-1`. `j` is not used in the bottom-up DP at all and is replaced with constant `n`. `q[j][k]` is uninitialized. However, the general idea is correct.

Comment: Your approach seems correct. However, maybe you should clarify your points better as it was a bit difficult to follow. If anyone is interested, his solution is similar to the method provided in this link: https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1168/lecture12.pdf, at page 5, see; "Extended bottom up cut rod" and "Print cut rod" functions.

Comment: @Maximus Thanks and apologies. I've added more explanation. Hope it helps.